# How should I decode a long variable which is encoded by Hashing.murmur3_32()?

Tags: java, hash, decode

I got a String variable in a Java program, and I know it is generated by following code:

```
public static String code(String text) {
    final byte[] bytes = text.getBytes();
    HashCode  hc = Hashing.murmur3_32().hashBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    long tmp = hc.asInt();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString((int) tmp));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

How can I decoded this variable to get the original text ?

Comment: If you ever find out how, be sure to write a CompSci paper about your achievement!

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/why-are-hash-functions-one-way-if-i-know-the-algorithm-why-cant-i-calculate-t

Comment: The entire point of a hash is that this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. A hash function is meant to be unidirectional. Also, there would be several different strings producing the same hash, so no possibility to recover the plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such method. The hash function is lossy.

When you think about it, the set of all possible strings is much larger than the set of all possible ints, making a two-way mapping impossible.

If it were possible to recover the string from its hash code, that would enable one to compress an arbitrary amount of data into a single int, and then to be able to perfectly reconstruct it.